# c# clean URL string from API

Tags: c#

Im calling an API that returns part of a URL that I have to concatenate on code after.

The value im getting is:

```
"\"SYSTEM\/PRODUCTION\/TEMP\/preauthletter_7470D75C-594D-4132-BAEE-F7339B034DD8_110220201138.pdf\""
```

When I try to concatenate to my base URL the result is an invalid URL because of the previews extras slash and quotes.

```
var result = _reportEngine.GetPreAuthorizationLetter().Result;
// result is the URL part having the extra slashes
result = string.Format(@"http://cloud.demo.com/{0}", result);
```

> Is there any .NET method that cleans this so I can get a valid URL.

The result expected should be:

```
http://cloud.demo.com/SYSTEM/PRODUCTION/TEMP/preauthletter_7470D75C-594D-4132-BAEE-F7339B034DD8_110220201138.pdf
```

**UPDATE**

The problem I guess is that API is returning as json instead of just pure string.

Comment: holup,  are the strings really escaped like this `\"` or is that just you copying and pasting from the IDE?

Comment: I would just replace '\' with '/' and trim double quotes. No need to get fancy here.

Answer (score 0):

Found how to solve it, I just had to deserialize it into a string:

```cs
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(result);
```

And voila!!